# Plot d3 chart on to Leaflet / Mapbox map

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I have a radial d3 chart that I would like to plot / overlay on to a Leaflet / Mapbox map at lat,long co-ordinates.

I have looked around and the solutions all seem to be plotting circles onto the map using cx, cy positions, which is not what I need.

Can I add the SVG surrounding the chart to the map?

Below is the code and a link to the radial chart (which may or may not be of any use for this question as I just want to know how to plot an SVG on to the map)

**CODE FOR D3 CHART**

```
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var twoPi = 2 * Math.PI; // Full circle
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var data = [{
  "range": "0-20",
  "count": 20
}, {
  "range": "21-40",
  "count": 10
}, {
  "range": "41-60",
  "count": 17
}, {
  "range": "61-80",
  "count": 49
}, {
  "range": "81-100",
  "count": 90
}];

var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return +d.count;
});

var percent = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return +d.count / 10;
});

var radiusBackground = .25;
var radiusForeground = .25;
var gap = 28;
var maxCount = max + percent;

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).x + "," + map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).y + ")");

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 10 + "," + height / 10 + ")")
  .attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

var background = g.selectAll(".twoPi")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "twoPi")
    .each(full);

var foreground = g.selectAll(".outerPath")
        .data(data).enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "outerPath")
        .each(drawArc);


map.on("viewreset", update);
update();

function update() {
    foreground.attr("transform", 
        function(d) { 
        return "translate("+ 
        map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).x/10000 +","+ 
        map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).y/10000 +")";
        }
    )
    background.attr("transform", 
        function(d) { 
        return "translate("+ 
        map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).x/10000 +","+ 
        map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).y/10000 +")";
        }
    )
}

function full() {

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(twoPi)
    .innerRadius(0 + gap * radiusBackground)
    .outerRadius(26 + gap * radiusBackground);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2.5) + "," + (height / 2.5) + ")")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("opacity", "0.5");
  radiusBackground++;
}

function drawArc(d, i) {

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(twoPi * (d.count / maxCount))
    .innerRadius(0 + gap * radiusForeground)
    .outerRadius(26 + gap * radiusForeground);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2.5) + "," + (height / 2.5) + ")")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("id", "path" + i)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "#8FAAE5");
    })
  radiusForeground++;

  var text = g.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12 + radiusForeground)
    .attr("dy", 20)
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

  text.append("textPath")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#path" + i)
    .text(d.count);
}
```

[CODEPEN LINK TO D3 CHART](http://codepen.io/alandunning/pen/KpKjBW)

**CODE FOR MAP (CURRENTLY WRONG I ASSUME)**

```
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'NAME HERE', {zoomControl: false}).setView([53.4054, -2.9858], 16);
var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var geojson = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [53.4054, -2.9858]
        },
        "properties": {
            "icon": {
                "className": "sensor-icon",
                //"html": "&#9660;",
                "iconSize": null
            }
        }
    },
];


myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;
        marker.setIcon(L.divIcon(feature.properties.icon));
    });
    myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

    new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addTo(map);

    var latLng = new L.LatLng(geojson[0].geometry.coordinates[0], geojson[0].geometry.coordinates[1]);
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panes. Specifically, you'll do `map.getPanes().overlayPane`, which will return an element you can append your SVG into.

Comment: Hi, as in: var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see. I was looking at the map code. This approach works fine for me, so I suspect it's not showing up on the map because of a display/CSS problem. Do you have a running example of the code you posted using the overlayPane?

Comment: Hi, it's not a css display issue. O think it may be something to do with the translating of the SVG element. The function latLngToLayerPoint is returning: 2629044,3094583, when I use these figures to translate, the SVG disappears?

Comment: I'm pretty sure latLng is undefined in the update() function as it's only defined in the scope of the layered event function. If you inspect your SVG element you may see that its transform attribute is invalid, which could cause the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76380/discussion-between-alan-and-ethan-jewett).

Comment: It is not undefined, it has the value from map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).x and map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).y?

Comment: Chat is not convenient for me, but maybe someone else can help there. I think this could be solved very quickly if you can provide a complete working example of all this in Codepen or JSFiddle.